# DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed in Roo project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-roo

I develop a Roo project and deploy to a Tomcat 6 server.
Up until now everything was working fine.

I deleted and re-added an entity.

Now everytime when I start Tomcat I get this exception in the Spring Tool Suite:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
Throwable occurred: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.ConversionServiceExposingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'applicationConversionService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [myproject.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean] for bean with name 'applicationConversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myproject.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [myproject.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean] for bean with name 'applicationConversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myproject.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
...
```

What do I need to do to make it work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spring is complainig about a bean not being available (probably the one you say you deleted).

```
 exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myproject.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean
```

try to search the config xml files & remove the reference made to this class, things should be back after that,

Comment: This class is something Roo generated so I didn't want to mess with it.I removed the reference in webmvc-config.xml but there's still the error with another class now:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)'

Comment: you have a tag which  looks something like this
`<bean ....>
<property name="something">
<ref> <bean class="class which has been removed"></ref>
</property>
</bean>`.. all you need to do is remove this reference

Comment: please check the config.. there must be another instance of the same or similar config,.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue.
The problem was that I disabled the "Project > Build Automatically" feature, so I had to manually build the project.
Once I manually built the project everything went back to normal. :)

So, don't forget to build the project before deploying it, or just re-enable the "Project > Build Automatically" feature.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your app deployed to Tomcat doesn't have a jar file in WEB-INF/lib that contains the class myproject.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean. I don't know what that class is or where you'd find it, but it's missing.

Comment: Its something normally generated automatically by Roo.

Answer (score 0):

my workaround (worked with eclipse and roo 1.1.5 as eclipse plugin)

- open ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean.java class
- delete class annotation @RooConversionService
- wait for roo update
- add back class annotation @RooConversionService
- wait for roo update and try again

Answer (score 0):

Inside of STS, click ->project->clean 
It clean and discard all build problems and built states, The next time a build occurs the projects will be rebuilt from scratch.